# AVAnimator crashes on device

Tags: ios, animation, video, mmap

I integrated the `AVAnimator` in my project to display video with transparent background.
On the simulator everything works perfectly fine. I can see the video, the background really is transparent and I can hear the audio.

But when I try to build and run on the device I get following error:

```
Assertion failure in -[SegmentedMappedData mapSegment], /transparentVideoTest/AVAnimator/SegmentedMappedData.m:300
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'mmap result EINVAL'
```

I'm not so familiar with mmap.

Can anyone tell me what the reason could be, when the mapping works on simulator but not on device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved it by going into Build Settings and changing the allowed architecture to be `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)` (Try to match your project settings to those of an [AVAnimator example project](http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/examples.html) )

Comment: javierx, nice find. Was the problem with 64 vs 32 ABI? I have not seen this issue myself and it might only show up with specific versions of xcode, but I am not positive about that.

Comment: I'm having the same issue even on the examples. Changing the allowed architecture as recommended here didn't help. It just spit out a bunch of link errors. @MoDJ: have you an example that runs on a device in iOS7 and built from Xcode 5.1.1?

Comment: Okay, I did get this working. I had to change the architecture as javierx suggested and I _also_ found that I needed to add the following compiler flag to maxvid_decode_arm.s: `-no-integrated-as` (in Targets->Build Phases->Compile Sources).

Comment: Yes, those flags are set in the examples. Also described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779502/xcode4-5-assembler-fails-to-compile-files-that-xcode4-4-handled-perfectly/13025159#comment18493082_13025159

Comment: Just an FYI, but this issue was recently addressed in the github source code so that one can build a fat binary that contains both 32 bit and 64 bit code and both will work properly. Note also that the -no-integrated-as flags and pre-ARC flags are no longer needed in the github version.